# How to replace a random number generation with a link?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm trying to replace video{79345394} (random number inside the brackets) with a link.  So far I have...

```
preg_replace('@video[{]([0-9])[}]@', $language[61].'<br /><a href="javascript:videoWith($1);">'.$language[62].'</a>', $chat_message);
```

It doesn't seem to be working, so help is very much appreciated!

Comment: If you want to escape the `{`, do `\{` instead of `[{]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind!  I just needed to add a {10}, so...

```
[0-9]{10}
```

Comment: You should rather do [0-9]{1,10} unless you are certain that your number will is 10 digits long.